# Wordpress comment box not visible

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I am trying to show a comment box under each post in wordpress. I have tried

```
<?php
comments_template('',true);
?>
```

but comment box is still invisible.

Any Help please

Comment: do you mean single post.describe why in index.php only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you place this in the right files?
Like page.php to display on pages.
And on single.php for single posts?
Single.php overrules index.php

Answer (score 0):

Do you see it when you view the page source? Styled to display:none ?

Comment: by editing "page.php" of my theme, i can see comment box in other pages but i want it to be appear only on index.php under the posts